# Vue JS computed property and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I want to turn an element invisible when a (bootstrap) tab is active.

So, the way I'm trying to do it is creating a computed property that returns if the  tab is active using jquery this way:

```
computed: {
    IsAbainteracoesAtiva: function () {
        return ($('div.active')[1].id == "interacoes")
    }
}
```

But this computed property always returns false, even if it's true. My guess is that Vue is not updating it.

Any sugestions? I'm opened to other solutions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the bootstrap tap is active with a click, otherwise correct me, and I'll come back with another answer.

```
// Simulate tab
<tab @click="toggleTabState"></tab>

// Simulate bootstrap element to show
<div v-if="tabIsOpen"></div>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tabIsOpen: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleTabState() {
      this.tabIsOpen = !this.tabIsOpen
    }
  }
}
```

Gonna need some of your HTML to see what else is going on. Are you iterating through a lot of elements with a **v-for**?

Comment: Yes, bootstrap tab is active with a click. And no, I'm just using a **v-if** to check.

Comment: Based on your answer, I made 'IsAbainteracoesAtiva' a "normal" property and in each tab I put a `v-on:click.prevent="IsAbainteracoesAtiva = false"` or a `v-on:click.prevent="IsAbainteracoesAtiva = false"` and it works now. Thanks!